# No Mouse pointer in CentOs7 with Synergy

Tags: centos, 64-bit, mouse

I am using Synergy Client in CentOs 7.

This is the problem that CentOs doesn't show mouse pointer when there is no mouse connected to the system.

Every time that I turn on my CentOs machine , I should connect the mouse to the machine otherwise CentOs doesn't show the mouse pointed for Synergy.

Everything is working with Synergy Client (click -right click , ...) but there is no mouse pointed!!!

How can I fix this problem? Synergy Client is running on CentOs 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this post: http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/3148/ubuntu-1310-no-cursor-visable-with-synergyc

Fix:
Move the mouse to the system where the mouse pointer is not visible, open the terminal and paste the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

This should resolve the problem for the current session and future sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution Michael Richmond presented.

Logging in, and with a terminal within that account executing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

however I also wanted the mouse visible at the login window as well. I used this link to figure it out

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/customizing-login-screen

it says to create or edit the `gdm` profile at `/etc/dconf/profile/gdm` with the following contents

```
user-db:user
system-db:gdm
file-db:/usr/share/gdm/greeter-dconf-defaults
```

I then created a file `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/01-Cursor`

and put the following contents

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor]
active=false
```

This essentially sets the same value in config file, but for the gdm login window.

After adding those files, I then executed `dconf update` to update the current running instance with the config setting.

At this point, I now have the synergy cursor available before and after login.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, all my LFS VM's defaulted to "USB Tablet" but CentOS VM's defaulted to "PS/2 Mouse". So my guess is the built-in templates (or whatever they are called) have that wrong. When creating a new VM, if I type in "LFS", I get Type "Linux" and Version "Linux 2.6/3.x (64-bit)" but if I type in "CentOS", I get Type "Linux" and Version "Red Hat (64 bit)". So, in my opinion, the "Red Hat (64 bit)" template should be changed to set Pointing Device to "USB Tablet".
some was unexpected at this time.